# Gradle support for building .Net projects

Tags: c#, gradle, build.gradle

I have a requirement to build my .Net project using gradle it seems gradle supports only C++ does anyone know how to build C# project using gradle ?

Comment: I don't know if it supports .NET, but some of my colleagues use it for Java projects, so it's definitely not just C++.

Comment: Yea it supports Java & Android i meant from microsoft perspective

Comment: You'll have to find a third-party C# plugin or implement your own (or declare ad-hoc tasks that call C# command line tools).

Comment: You can use the msbuild plugin to accomplish that (https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-msbuild-plugin)

Comment: thanks Ran yea im using it ..

Comment: how well does that plugin work?

Comment: plugin works well except for vdproj files

Answer (score 4):

Here you have another Net plugin that also works with mono: https://github.com/bamboo/gradle-dotnet-plugins